# csv writer format cell in python

Tags: python, csv

I write into a csv by this function:

```
def write_csv(hlavicka: Tuple[str, ...], zaznam: list, pomocne_csv: str) -> None:
    if not os.path.isfile(pomocne_csv):
        with open(pomocne_csv, "w", encoding=cfg.ENCODING, newline="") as soubor:
            writer = csv.writer(soubor, delimiter=cfg.DELIMITER)
            writer.writerow(hlavicka)
    with open(pomocne_csv, "a", encoding=cfg.ENCODING, newline="") as soubor:
        writer = csv.writer(soubor, delimiter=cfg.DELIMITER)
        writer.writerows([zaznam])
```

However, when I open the csv in MS Office, I see that long numbers are in the scientific notation. For example `102043292003060000` is displayed as `1.02E+17`. Of course, I put `102043292003060000` into my write_csv() function.

The problem is that when I read the csv using:

```
def generuj_zaznamy(input_path):
    with open(input_path, "r", encoding="cp1250") as file_object:
        reader = csv.reader(file_object, delimiter=";")

        for entry in enumerate(reader, start=1):

            print(entry)
```

I got `1.02E+17` instead of `102043292003060000`.

Is there a way how to format the cell as a number directly in csv.writer or csv.reader? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is an Excel issue exclusively, it has nothing to do with your Python code. Excel tries to 'help' you by converting your data to what it thinks you'd rather like. But obviously this almost never works as you'd expect. Solution, in a nutshell: if you want to do science, then don't use Excel. https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-37176926

Comment: @Guillaume Thanks for your comment, see my edit, please.

Comment: Please open your CSV with a simple text editor, and check if your huge numbers are stored like 102043292003060000 or 1.02E+17. If it is the former, then it's an Excel issue, if the later, then it's an issue with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the text editor like notepad.exe to open the csv file, you should see the value of a long numbers accurately. So, the problem comes from office excel but not csv.writer.

If you want to see the long numbers accurately from csv file, you should create a new xlsx file and use the function(Data->Get External Data->From text) to select the csv file for importing, and then choose the data format of the column as Text.

Edited:

I tried the code and it seems that the problem also happens to pandas.DataFrame.to_csv() but not only csv.writer() when the length of the number comes to 20 or more, which is out of the range of np.int64.
I readed the offical document and seems that float_format arg can't solve this problems.

The solution I can give now is here, if you can read the original data in string format for the length of the number more than 20:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.DataFrame(["3100000035155588379531799826432", "3100000035155588433002733375488", "3100000035155588355694446120960"])
df = "\t" + df
print(df)
df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False, header=False)

rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
big_nums = rng.random(10) * (10**19) # OverflowError while comes to 10**20
df = pd.DataFrame(big_nums, dtype=np.int64).astype(str)
# df = "\t" + df
print(df)
df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

and the output will like that:

```
                                   0
0  \t3100000035155588379531799826432
1  \t3100000035155588433002733375488
2  \t3100000035155588355694446120960
                      0
0   6369616873214542848
1   2697867137638703104
2    409735239361946880
3    165276355285290944
4   8132702392002723840
5   9127555772777217024
6   6066357757671798784
7   7294965609839983616
8   5436249914654228480
9  -9223372036854775808
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, see my edit, please.

Comment: @vojtam It seems that pandas also get this problem, I tried to solve it but unfortunately it seems that I can't solve it fully.